# Sql -> Monitor if CPU rises above a treshold and log queries

Tags: sql-server, logging, monitoring, cpu-usage

Is there some way to monitor the CPU usage of a MS-SQL process and if it rises above a certain treshold, log the queries which get executed while the CPU usage is above the treshold?

Basically, the problem that I am having is that one of my databases becomes really slow regularly - several times a day. During the periods when the database is slow, the CPU usage of the SQL process is around the 90%- 100% and all the queries are timing out.

I am currently looking into ways to develop a small application to do that monitoring for me using .NET, but I thought that there might already be something existing for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try sqlmonitor from redgate.

Its quite good at answering questions like "Usually everything works nice, but at a certain point in time something goes wrong".